# android- single server/ multiple clients?

Tags: android, client-server

I'm working on programming a live support chatting here, but the problem I faced is how to this server I made is receiving only one client to chat with.

can any pro explain to me to make the server receive more than one client at same time ?

and there is another problem which is :
If I close the chat activity then come back to make new chat through the application, the server couldn't response to it.

any suggestion please ...

**Server Side:**

```
public class TCPServer extends Thread {

public static final int SERVERPORT = 7777;
private boolean running = false;
private PrintWriter mOut;
private OnMessageReceived messageListener;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //opens the window where the messages will be received and sent
    ServerBoard frame = new ServerBoard();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

/**
 * Constructor of the class
 * @param messageListener listens for the messages
 */
public TCPServer(OnMessageReceived messageListener) {
    this.messageListener = messageListener;
}


/**
 * Method to send the messages from server to client
 * @param message the message sent by the server
 */
public void sendMessage(String message){
    if (mOut != null && !mOut.checkError()) {
        mOut.println(message);
        mOut.flush();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();


    running = true;

    try {
        System.out.println("S: Connecting...");

        //create a server socket. A server socket waits for requests to come in over the network.
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);

        //create client socket... the method accept() listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it.
        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("S: Receiving...");

        try {

            //sends the message to the client
            mOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())), true);

            //read the message received from client
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));


            //in this while we wait to receive messages from client (it's an infinite loop)
            //this while it's like a listener for messages
            while (running) {
                String message = in.readLine();

                if (message != null && messageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from ServerBoard class
                    messageListener.messageReceived("Student: "+message);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("S: Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            client.close();
            System.out.println("S: Done.");
        }

        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("S: Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


//Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be   implemented in the ServerBoard
//class at on startServer button click
public interface OnMessageReceived {
    public void messageReceived(String message);
}

}
```

**for the client I separate them into two activities :**

```
public class TCPMainActivity extends Activity
{
private ListView mList;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;
private TCPClient mTcpClient;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tcpmain);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);

    //relate the listView from java to the one created in xml
    mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, arrayList);
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // connect to the server
    new connectTask().execute("");

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String message = editText.getText().toString();

            //add the text in the arrayList
            arrayList.add("Student: " + message);

            //sends the message to the server
            if (mTcpClient != null) {
                mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
            }

            //refresh the list
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });

}

public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {

    @Override
    protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

        //we create a TCPClient object and
        mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        //in the arrayList we add the messaged received from server
        arrayList.add("Managment: "+values[0]);
        // notify the adapter that the data set has changed. This means that new message received
        // from server was added to the list
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all courses
    }

}
 protected void onStop() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     //mTcpClient.stopClient();
     Log.e("TCP Client", "Stooped");
     super.onStop(); 

 }

protected void onStart() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onStart();


 }
protected void onResume() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onResume();
 //new connectTask().execute("");
 }




    /* public void onDestroy() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onDestroy();
     }
     */
}
```

**the second one is :**

```
public class TCPClient {

private String serverMessage;
public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.0.102"; //your computer IP address
public static final int SERVERPORT = 7777;
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
private boolean mRun = false;

PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;
Socket socket;

/**
 *  Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
 */
public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Sends the message entered by client to the server
 * @param message text entered by client
 */
public void sendMessage(String message){
    if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
    }
}

public void stopClient(){
    mRun = false;
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {

    mRun = true;

    try {
        if (socket != null)
            socket.close();

        //here you must put your computer's IP address.
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
         socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        try {

            //send the message to the server
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

            //receive the message which the server sends back
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
            while (mRun) {
                serverMessage = in.readLine();

                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                }
                serverMessage = null;

            }


            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");


        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

        } finally {
            //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
            // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

    }

}

//Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
//class at on asynckTask doInBackground
public interface OnMessageReceived {
    public void messageReceived(String message);
}
}
```

thanking you in advance.